# Compare AWS-lambda, Azure functions and Google Cloud Function

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions, google-cloud-functions

I want to develop a serverless project by selecting aws-lambda, azure function or google cloud function. Then I want to compare each one in order to select the best one for my project.

I need to select the most stable serverless technology for my project.

Is there any material comparing these technologies?

Is there any supported framework for these serverless technologies?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Compare AWS-Lambda, Azure Functions and Google Cloud Functions

1. **Supported Languages** 
   **AWS lambda**- Node.js, Python, Java, C# (.net core)
   **Azure Function** - Node.js, Python, PHP, F#, C#, batch, bash 
   **Google Cloud Functions** Node.js
2. **Maximum execution time per request** 
       **AWS lambda**- 300 seconds (5 minutes) 
       **Azure Function** - 300 seconds (5 minutes) 
       **Google Cloud Functions**  540 sec (9 minutes)
3. **Log Management** 
       **AWS lambda**- Cloud watch 
       **Azure Function** - Azure Storage
       **Google Cloud Functions**  Cloud Logging
4. **Scalability & availability**
           **AWS lambda**- Automatic scaling  
           **Azure Function** -Automatic scaling 
           **Google Cloud Functions**  Automatic scaling
5. **HTTP End point**
               **AWS lambda**- AWS API Gateway  
               **Azure Function** -HTTP Trigger
               **Google Cloud Functions**  HTTP Trigger
6. **Pricing**
       Note: These are per-call fees.  Charging for CPU and RAM time is common, generally exceeds the per-call fee, and should be considered. 
                   **AWS lambda**-$0.20/1M executions  
                   **Azure Function**-$0.20/1M executions  
                   **Google Cloud Functions** $0.40/M execution, no extra for HTTP calls [pricing details](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing)
7. **Function Limit**
                   **AWS lambda**-Unlimited functions 
                   **Azure Function**-Unlimited functions 
                   **Google Cloud Functions** 1,000 per project
8. **Concurrent executions**
                   **AWS lambda**-100 parallel executions per account per region but users can increase it 
                   **Azure Function** -No limit
                   **Google Cloud Functions**  HTTP no limit, 1,000 non-HTTP
9. **Deployments**
                       **AWS lambda**-Zip, AWS-S3 or edit code inline  
                       **Azure Function**-Anything an Azure WebApp can handle: FTP(S), KUDU, Web Deploy, One Drive\DropBox, Git\Local Git\TFS\etc, Visual Studio\XCode\Eclipse\etc, PowerShell\Cli\Probably all the SDK's
                       **Google Cloud Functions** CLI, ZIP upload, inline web editor, Cloud Storage or Cloud Source Repositories

Every one welcome to corrected information and add new information.

Comment: AWS Lambda is the only one that is not in preview, beta, or alpha.

Comment: @hellomichibye what you mean by not preview?

Comment: It means that Lambda is the only one that is GA and prod-ready since it has been introduced two years ago while the other offerings were launched this year (2016).

Comment: Azure Functions are in preview = beta. Googles Cloud Functions are in closed alpha. AWS Lambda is the only service that is ready for production according to the provider.

Comment: The 100 parallel executions per account per region in Lambda is a soft limit. You can increase it.

Comment: @hellomichiby check again is there any wrong answer ?

Comment: Thank you for your support. plz add new infomation

Comment: Google Cloud Functions supports Node.js, not just plain JavaScript.

Comment: "Node.js, Python, PHP, F#, C#, batch, bash" - I signed up for free azure account to test PHP but half of those languages are not even there. There's like js, f and c or wehatever. Don't remember.

Comment: What is the equivalent functionality to **Lambda Layers** in Azure and Google Function? (or is there even one?)

Answer (score 27):

**AWS Lambda vs Azure Functions vs Google Cloud Functions**

Here is an aggregation of all serverless features provided by different cloud vendors. This is based on my perspective.

> If anything has changed over a period of time or you want to add anything
>   new, please feel free to comment and lets maintain this to track
>   various features.

```
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|     Category    | AWS Lambda          |    Azure              | Google Cloud      |
|                 |                     |  Functions            |  Functions        |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 1. Version      | Production ready    | Preview - Beta        | Closed Alpha      |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 2. Supported    | Nodejs, Python,     | Nodejs, Python,       | Javascript        |
| Languages       |      Java           |   PHP, F#, C#         |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 3. Dependency   | Compile all         | Using                 | Using             |
| Management      | external packages   | package.json – nodejs | package.json      |
|                 | and zip the         | project.json – F#,C#  |                   |
|                 | source code         |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|                 | S3, DynamoDB        | Bindings/Triggers     | HTTP              |
|                 | Kinesis             |                       | functions:        |
|                 | Streams             | Scheduler             | Http Triggers     |
|                 | SNS, SES            | Http(webhook)         | Webhooks (drive,  |
|                 | Cognito             | Azure Storage         |  gmail, calendar) |
|                 | Cloud Formation     | Events Hubs           |                   |
| 4. Event        | Cloud Watch         | Queues, Tables        | Background        |
| Sources         | Code Commit         | DocumentDB(No-sql)    | functions:        |
|                 | Scheduled Events    | Notification Hub      | Cloud Pub/Sub,    |
|                 | Config              | Twilio                | Cloud Storage     |
|                 | Echo,               |                       |                   |
|                 | Alexa               |                       | Pub/Sub:          |
|                 | APIGateway          |                       | Cloud Logging     |
|                 |                     |                       | Gmail, Twilio     |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 5. Granular     | IAM                 |                       |                   |
|  IAM            | policy              | Not Yet               | Not Yet           |
|                 | can be Attached     |                       |                   |
|                 | to Lambda.          |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|                 | - On top of Linux   | - On top of Windows   |                   |
| 6. Architecture | - Memory allocated  | - Memory allocated    |                   |
|                 |    per function.    |    per app service.   | Not Specified     |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|                 | No persistent       | Env variables         |                   |
|                 |  storage.           | can be set in         |                   |
| 7. Persistent   | Completely          | App services          | Not Specified     |
|  Storage        | Stateless           | which can be used     |                   |
|                 |                     | in functions.         |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 8. HTTP         | APIGateway          | HTTP webhooks         | HTTP Trigger      |
| Endpoint        |                     |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 9. Log          | Cloud               | Kudu Console          | Stackdriver       |
| Management      | watch               |                       | Logging           |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 10. Maximum     | 300 seconds         | No limit              | No limit          |
| Execution       | (5 mins)            |                       |                   |
| Time            |                     |                       |                   |
| per request     |                     |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 11. Concurrent  | 100                 | 10 instances          | Not Specified     |
| Executions      | parallel            | which is several      |                   |
|                 | Executions, but     | 100 executions        |                   |
|                 | Can be increased    |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 12. Deployment  | Zip upload          | Git, dropbox,         | Zip upload,       |
|                 | to Lambda/s3,       | visual studio,        | Cloud Storage,    |
|                 | Serverless          | One drive,            | Cloud Source      |
|                 | Framework           | Kudu Console          | repositories,     |
|                 |                     |                       | Git               |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 13. Maximum     |                     |                       | 20 functions      |
|     no. of      | No limit            | Not Specified         | per project       |
|  Functions      |                     |                       |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| 14. Pricing     | Request Charges:    | Request Charges:      | Unknown until     |
|                 | $0.20 / 1M requests | $0.20 / 1M requests   | Open beta         |
|                 |                     |                       |                   |
|                 | Compute Charges:    | Compute Charges:      |                   |
|                 | $0.00001667 / GB-s  | $0.000008 / GB-s      |                   |
+-----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Well compiled information. On a sidenote: how did you generate that nifty table format ?

Comment: @Angle.Bracket Here is the link to generate github's readme like tables. http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: Could you please update your answer based on all that happened since Nov 2016? That'll be helpful.

Comment: someone correct me if I'm wrong, but Azure isn't limited to 20 functions per project anymore. (I just made 21 to see.)

Comment: Note that Amazon Lambda requires you to use their Gateway service if you want to trigger the function over HTTP(s). It's priced at $3.50 extra per million requests, therefore making the bulk for the cost.

Answer (score 3):

Few updates (2/18/2017):

- Azure Function has GA-ed Nov 2016
- AWS support C# but only .NET Core
- You can have up to 100 Azure Function-Apps, each can contain many functions
- Azure Function Consumption tier currently has 300 sec max runtime per function invocation
- Azure Function compute price has updated at GA from $0.000008 / GB-s to  $0.00001667 / GB-s

Answer (score 3):

There's now a serverless framework that supports cloud provider agnostic code and provides a unified experience for developing, testing and deploying your functions using abstractions.

Have a look at https://serverless.com

It supports all 3 providers, though not all languages are supported. The lowest common denominator is Node.js/JavaScript